# Docker image for build BizTalk projects in GitLab

Tags: docker, biztalk

We need a Docker image to build BizTalk projects.

We use as base image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019, but we can't add the features to build BizTalk projects because internally this image is using Visual Studio 2022.

Do you know how to add BizTalk features to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each version of BizTalk has a particular version of BizTalk and it needs to be either Enterprise or Professional.

- [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2020](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2020), Visual Studio 2019 (min Version 16.4.0)
- [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2016), Visual Studio 2015
- [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-biztalk-server-2013-and-2013-r2), Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 respectively.

So first you need to have the correct version of Visual Studio, and then you have to run the BizTalk developer setup and at least install the SDK. For 2020 you also need to install the [Developer Tools](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/biztalk-server-team-blog/biztalk-server-2020-setup-developer-tools-installation/ba-p/1225906) from the marketplace